# How to start a service automatically after openning an application?

Tags: applescript, automator, firefox, services

For example, I have a service that I want it to be started automatically when I open `Firefox`.

I know how to write scripts as services in `automator`, but I don't know how to make a hook that when `Firefox` is openned, it started the service.

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides starting both programs via a script as you told I can only think of [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) which is a powerful macro program for Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Lion and Snow Leopard.

You can do a lot of crazy stuff with it. And you can trigger macros when programs are running or not running which is what you want.